# React.Js TransitionGroup ( react-transition-group ) is not working

Tags: reactjs, gsap, react-transition-group

I am trying to call the special lifecycle hooks from react-transition-group to implement animation using gsap. But TransitionGroup component is blocking the Box component from rendering, If I remove the TransitionGroup component from the page component then the Box component render .. Please help me find out the issue

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/TransitionGroup'
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap'
import './App.css';
class Box extends React.Component {
  componentWillEnter (callback) {
    const el = this.container;
    TweenMax.fromTo(el, 0.3, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});
  }
  componentWillLeave (callback) {
    const el = this.container;
    TweenMax.fromTo(el, 0.3, {y: 0, opacity: 1}, {y: -100, opacity: 0, onComplete: callback});
  }
  render () {
    return <div className="box" ref={c => this.container = c}/>;
  }
}

export default class Page extends React.Component {
  state = {
    shouldShowBox: true
  };

  toggleBox = () => {
    this.setState({
      shouldShowBox: !this.state.shouldShowBox
    })
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <TransitionGroup>
          { this.state.shouldShowBox && <Box/>}
        </TransitionGroup>
        <button
            className="toggle-btn"
            onClick={this.toggleBox.bind(this)}
          >
          toggle
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My package.json is

```
  "name": "react-with-gsap",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "gsap": "^1.20.3",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "victory": "^0.24.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do not use `react-motion`?

Comment: @oklas, I have used react-motion and I like that ..I just wanted to try gsap with react once ..  but  TransitionGroup is not working .

Answer (score 0):

The custom lifecycle methods were removed in the `v2` version of `react-transition-groups`

From the migration guide:

> The old `<TransitionGroup>` component managed transitions through custom
>   static lifecycle methods on its children. In v2 we removed that API in
>   favor of requiring that `<TransitionGroup>` be used with a `<Transition>`
>   component, and using traditional prop passing to communicate between
>   the two.

You can still use the `v1` release if you prefer the custom lifecycle hooks as it is still actively maintained, as per the docs:

> For a drop-in replacement for `react-addons-transition-group` and
>   `react-addons-css-transition-group`, use the v1 release, which is still
>   actively maintained. Documentation and code for that release are
>   available on the `v1-stable` branch.